# Multiple tables in a single application

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Can a a single android app have multiple tables in the same database whih is created by 2 different class extending SQLIteOpenHelper?

Because my app has 2 tables created from 2 different helper classes but only one is created and throws an error at the other saying table doesn't exist eventhough Create Table If Not Exists statement exists

Comment: Why do you want to do that? In general, One `SQLiteOpenHelper` meant to hold one database and it should hold all related tables. If you are thinking, to put multiple tables from multiple classes, then your design is totally wrong.

Comment: I thought the code would be easier to access if it was from different classes

Comment: No. You will lose the readability and understandability of your code.

Comment: Yeah i merged both the classes and the table is created now... Why is is like this though?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create any tables using the same SQLiteOpenHelper to avoid any problems.